# "This feature is only available for view with a strongly typed model" in VS 2013, ASP,C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional

In MVC during `Add View` the `Model Class` dropdown is blank and read only (ASP.NET, C#)

On hovering this dropdown, the message showing is

```
This feature is only available for view with a strongly typed model
```

I want to add the class created by me, and want to use strongly typed model.

Comment: Have you built your project? AFAIK the designer can't see types that haven't been compiled yet. (I'm assuming you mean ASP.NET MVC here)

Comment: Hi Sachin! Your question is not clear, which programming language do you use, which platform do you develop for? Please be more specific, otherwise it will be difficult to help you... If possible, show some code and tell us what you tried already.

Comment: @nburk Question has been Updated, I am not able to post pic, can i send you on your emaid id, to make clarify the scenerio

Comment: You probably need to tick the 'use strongly typed view' or 'use a model'

Comment: @devqon there is no checkbox showing in "Add View" window, just having the option of View Name and template name. Model Name is blank, read only, not clickable and i m not getting any of checkbox there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of choosing "Template: Empty (without model)", for example:

[image: Template: Empty (without model)]

You should choose "Template: Empty" and specify the Model class, like this:

[image: Template: Empty (with model)]

Which will automatically insert the `@model` directive into the view.

Comment: No dropdown for Template is present. Model Class dropdown is present but **disabled**. Cannot even create a view because the _add_ button is also disabled.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Yes, I am using VS 2013 (ultimate)

Comment: Perhaps you haven't installed all the prerequisites? I have installed both MVC 3 and MVC 4. See here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Answer (score 1):

You have to build the project first.  All that really does is add at the top of the view:

```
@model Some.Model.Type
```

So you can just add that yourself.

Comment: I am not able to create View with strongly typed model, thats the issue, I cant post the Image for that because i am new user of stack overflow.  In "Add View" window, just having the option of View Name and template name edditable but Model Name is blank, read only, not clickable and i m not getting any of checkbox there

Comment: "Strong typing" is not determined by the add new view dialog; it's determined by the @model attribute.  Try creating a view without a model, manually enter the model as I have illustrated, rebuild, and see if the intellisense works.